# Improve my parsing of JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

Right now, I am currently parsing this JSON in a way that I feel can be improved upon.  I am new at JSON, but I would expect there to be a better way of doing it than what I am currently doing.

Here is the JSON **that is returned to me** from Stripe's API (sensitive data removed):

```
Stripe\Customer JSON: { "id": "cus_6sncrSm", "object": "customer", "created": 1440825, "livemode": false, "description": null, "email": null, "shipping": null, "delinquent": false, "metadata": [], "subscriptions": { "object": "list", "total_count": 1, "has_more": false, "url": "\/v1\/customers\/cus_6smcrSm\/subscriptions", "data": [ { "id": "sub_6smHbrP", "plan": { "id": "yearly", "interval": "year", "name": "yearly", "created": 1429255, "amount": 5000, "currency": "usd", "object": "plan", "livemode": false, "interval_count": 1, "trial_period_days": 7, "metadata": [], "statement_descriptor": "yearly" }, "object": "subscription", "start": 1440627, "status": "trialing", "customer": "cus_6OncrSm", "cancel_at_period_end": false, "current_period_start": 1440821627, "current_period_end": 1441426427, "ended_at": null, "trial_start": 1440821627, "trial_end": 1441426427, "canceled_at": null, "quantity": 1, "application_fee_percent": null, "discount": null, "tax_percent": null, "metadata": [] } ] }, "discount": null, "account_balance": 0, "currency": "usd", "sources": { "object": "list", "total_count": 1, "has_more": false, "url": "\/v1\/customers\/cus_6smcrSm\/sources", "data": [ { "id": "card_16f0ioKTaUqqN0knY", "object": "card", "last4": "4242", "brand": "Visa", "funding": "credit", "exp_month": 10, "exp_year": 2017, "fingerprint": "Y1GhThdTv", "country": "US", "name": "blah@yahoo.com", "address_line1": null, "address_line2": null, "address_city": null, "address_state": null, "address_zip": null, "address_country": null, "cvc_check": null, "address_line1_check": null, "address_zip_check": null, "tokenization_method": null, "dynamic_last4": null, "metadata": [], "customer": "cus_6hkjhkj9" } ] }, "default_source": "card_160knY" }
```

The main problem I am having is that I have to convert the above into a string manually and then remove the prefix (which is the "Stripe\Customer JSON:" part).  **Here is what I'm currently doing to parse it:**

```
$json = strval(\Stripe\Customer::retrieve($user->stripe_id));

//Trim the prefix
$json = substr($json, 21);
$data = json_decode($json, true);
$current_period_end = $data['subscriptions']['data'][0]['current_period_end'];
```

The reason why I think there is a better way to do this is because I find it hard to believe that every time I receive JSON I need to convert it to a String and then find out if there is a prefix and then cut the prefix off before I can turn it into an associative array so I can use it.

Please tell me there is a better way and show me how to do it. Thank you.

On a side note, I am using Laravel, if there are any relevant features to benefit from therein I'm all ears.

Comment: In case it helps someone else, the following will also work.  It's convenient because you can access any data attribute in the same object if you just change the last variable, or access other data attributes by simple modifications in the following chain that correspond to the JSON labels:  $current_period_end = $customer_object->subscriptions->data[0]->current_period_end;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using the [stripe-php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php) library, you should be interacting with the objects provided, not turning them into strings and parsing that.

For example, the call to `\Stripe\Customer::retrieve($user->stripe_id)` returns a `\Stripe\Customer` object, just like in Laravel where `\App\User::find(1)` returns an `\App\User` object.

Instead of converting this `\Stripe\Customer\` object to a string, use it as it was meant to be used.

If you want the subscriptions, try:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($user->stripe_id);
// $customer is now a \Stripe\Customer object

$subscriptions = $customer->subscriptions;
// $subscriptions is now an array of \Stripe\Subscription objects

foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {
    $current_period_end = $subscription->current_period_end;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.  It's confusing since this object begins with Stripe\Customer JSON: and then gives a JSON string, but I did notice in the docs that "if you're using API bindings, we will convert the response to the appropriate language-specific object."  I was wondering if you know of a place where I can get more examples of how to manipulate this object. For example, can I do something like $current_period_end = $customer->subscriptions->current_period_end; and it looks like I can't because it's an object within an object, but I'm not great at manipulating nestled objects yet.

Comment: In case it helps someone else, the following will also work.  This way, you can access any data attribute in the same object if you just change the last variable:  $current_period_end = $customer_object->subscriptions->data[0]->current_period_end;

Comment: @user3089840 When you pass the object to the `strval()` function, it calls the object's `toString()` method to convert it to a string. The output you see ("Stripe\Customer JSON: { ... }") is what they return from the call to `toString()`. I didn't see any real useful documentation on the php api library. The information I gave above came from looking into the code (a great way to learn).

Comment: @user3089840 You can't do `$customer->subscriptions->current_period_end`, because `$customer->subscriptions` is an array. You could do `$customer->subscriptions[0]->current_period_end`, if you knew you'd only ever want the first subscription. You may also want to read up on the [Cashier](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/billing) documentation or [code](https://github.com/laravel/cashier), as they may have already abstracted out whatever functionality you're trying to get at.

Comment: I think I'd only need the 1st subscription because this data is being returned based on me providing them with a particular user's ID.  I have looked through the Cashier code and tried various things, but either they don't provide exactly what I was looking for or I couldn't figure it out.  The closest I could find was this:  $last_four = $this_customer->sources->retrieve($this_customer->default_source)->last4; which worked to obtain the last 4 of a credit card, but I couldn't get it to work for the current_period_end value.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely shouldn't need to clean up the JSON response like that. Then again, you don't need to use Stripe's library directly anyway, because Laravel has an interface specifically made to integrate with Stripe: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/billing

Once you've properly configured it, you'll be able to use it directly from your user model with methods like `$user->subscribed()` or `$user->onGracePeriod()`

Comment: As far as I can tell, Laravel doesn't let you access quite a few of the items from Stripe's library, such as  current_period_end.  If you can find a way to use Laravel to access "current_period_end", let me know, as I wasn't able to fineone.